# NFC NdefFormatable class connect() throws IOException

Tags: java, android, nfc

```
NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
if (ndefFormatable == null) {
    throw new TagException("Not a NDEF formatable tag");
}

try {       
    if(!ndefFormatable.isConnected())
    {
        ndefFormatable.connect();
    }

    tagData.setUniqueId(tag.getId());
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = buildNdefMessage(tagData);
    ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);
}
catch (FormatException ex) {
    throw new TagException(ex.getMessage());
}
finally {
    ndefFormatable.close();
}
```

When it goes into the try and execute connect() it always throws IOException

can any one help me out.

Comment: invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x54f66000) size(466560)

Comment: the **whole** log please

Comment: Is the exception thrown upon `connect()` or `format()`? Is your tag still in range when you exectue that code? In what thread (I.e. how do you create it?) do you execute that code?

Comment: exception is on on connect() , i have separate thread for its execution... and its already in doInBackground().

Comment: You might want to try manual creation of a worker thread instead of using an AsyncTask then. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23827996/2425802) for a problem that sounds very similar.

Comment: i tried with worker thread but facing same issue..

Comment: Do you immediately connect to the tag after it has been scanned or do you do other things in between? Also I assume that you do **not** try to single-step debug this part of your code, right?