# Android NFC read ISO15693 RFID Tag

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I am trying to read an ISO15693 RFID tag with the nfc android library:

Here is more info on the Tag: http://img42.com/gw07d+

The Tag ID is read correctly but the data in the tag is not.

`onCreate` Method:

```
// initialize NFC
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,   this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

`onNewIntent` method:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        currentTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        byte[] id = currentTag.getId();
        Tag_data_TextDisplay.setText("TagId:" + Common.getHexString(id));

        for (String tech : currentTag.getTechList()) {

            if (tech.equals(NfcV.class.getName())) {
                NfcV nfcvTag = NfcV.get(currentTag);

                try {
                    nfcvTag.connect();
                    txtType.setText("Hello NFC!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open a connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    byte[] cmd = new byte[]{
                            (byte) 0x00, // Flags
                            (byte) 0x23, // Command: Read multiple blocks
                            (byte) 0x00, // First block (offset)
                            (byte) 0x04  // Number of blocks
                    };
                    byte[] userdata = nfcvTag.transceive(cmd);

                    userdata = Arrays.copyOfRange(userdata, 0, 32);
                    txtWrite.setText("DATA:" + Common.getHexString(userdata));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred while reading!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`userdata` is contains a single byte with value `0x02` (`{ 0x02 }`) right after the transceive method finished.

Comment: and what should it read?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Where I read the tag http://img42.com/mHBPa+

Comment: Would be helpful if you could show us the actual result of `nfcvTag.transceive(cmd);` (without padding to 32 bytes). Moreover, could you make sure that your byte-array to hex conversion padds each byte to two hex digits (otherwise it will be difficult to interpret the value).

Comment: @MichaelRoland I updated the question with the byte to hex converter: Here is the result of .transceive  http://img42.com/7c30r+

Comment: Can you please tell what is happening in your Common class ? can you please share code of your common class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you receive a value of `{ 0x02 }` from the `transceive` method. As found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24167513/2425802) this may happen when you use unaddressed commands. Hence, you should always send addressed commands through `NfcV` (as this seems to be supported across all NFC chipsets on Android devices). In your case, you could use something like this to generate an addressed READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS command:

```
int offset = 0;  // offset of first block to read
int blocks = 1;  // number of blocks to read
byte[] cmd = new byte[]{
        (byte)0x60,                  // flags: addressed (= UID field present)
        (byte)0x23,                  // command: READ MULTIPLE BLOCKS
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,  // placeholder for tag UID
        (byte)(offset & 0x0ff),      // first block number
        (byte)((blocks - 1) & 0x0ff) // number of blocks (-1 as 0x00 means one block)
};
System.arraycopy(id, 0, cmd, 2, 8);
byte[] response = nfcvTag.transceive(cmd);
```

Comment: What does `System.arraycopy(id, 0, cmd, 2, 8); ` do?

Comment: As explained in the Java documentation: "*Copies [8] elements from the array [`id`], starting at offset [0], into the array [`cmd`], starting at offset [2].*"

Comment: In this context it copies the UID (address) of the tag (that you previously retrieved with `byte[] id = currentTag.getId();`) into the command frame (over the placeholder bytes).