# I can not read / write NFC tag (NfcV)

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I am developing a mobile application for Android for reading and writing data on NFC. While working with the M24SR04 chip from ST, then everything worked. After the transition to the chip M24LR64ER (also from ST) - ceased.
The application can not pass the conditions(presented below).

This can be done using other applications. NFC application tools allow you to use only the initial reading of parameters (type, technology, serial number, DSFID).

The NfcV reader application (from ST) easily performs all possible actions. The lines "E / NfcHandover: invalid NDEF entry" are not in the logs.

I thought that this does not support NDEF, but the NfcV-reader application both reads and writes NDEF messages.

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NFC read ISO15693 RFID Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405558/android-nfc-read-iso15693-rfid-tag)

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.java

Comment: The fact is that the condition:  

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || 
    NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) 

is false in my case. Therefore, the program itself does not proceed to the process of reading or writing. I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: some `NFC` controllers also do not fully support `NFCV` ...

Comment: How can I read or write anything on this chip?

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00103491.pdf ... says that "once the tag is identified as 15693 ST product is possible to read block or write block". it might be missing from the `tech‐list`.

Comment: What technologies/tech-list do other reader applications (not the one from ST) show for the tag? Do they include Ndef/NdefFormatable?